# Nu HTML Checker

Tags: html

I keep getting this error: Bad value 30px for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead. From line 50, column 15; to line 50, column 88 ↩

Any help would be appreciated

For this code:

```
<header class="page-header">
  <img src="img/favicon.png" alt="logo" class="page-header__item">
  <nav class="main-navigation page-header__item">
    <ul role="menubar" class="navigation-list">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="index.html" role="menuitem" class="navigation-list_item navigation-list_active">Home</a>
      </li >
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="about.html" role="menuitem" class="navigation-list__item">About</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="contact.html" role="menuitem" class="navigation-list__item">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="work.html" role="menuitem" class="navigation-list__item">Work</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>



      <section class="profile">
      <img src="img/chrisuhler.jpg" class="profile__portrait" alt="chrisuhlerportrait">
      ​
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      ​
      <p>
        My name is Chris Uhler. I am web developer from, Medford Oregon
      </p>
      ​
      <button type="button">Check out some of my code</button>
      <button class="button__secondary">Secondary Button</button>



    ​
    <footer class="page-footer">
      <p>Find Me on<p>
        <div class="social-media">
          <img src="img/Facebook.svg" width= "30px" height="30px" alt="facebook" />
          ​
          <img src="img/twitter.svg" width= "30px" height= "30px" alt="twitter" />
          ​
          <img src="img/linkedin.svg" width= "30px" height= "30px" alt="linkedin" />
        </div>
    </footer>
    ​
    <script src="js/tota11y.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS expects dimensions to have units, such as `30px`, `3em` etc. The `width` and `height` attributes of HTML can only be expressed in pixels, and should be a plain number. Thus, you should write `width="30"` instead.